# How to properly destroy a class

Tags: ruby, finalizer, resource-cleanup

In Ruby, I have a DAO class, which is extended by a class that makes managing the connections easier, which is extended by a class that represents and manipulates data in a DB, which is further extended by another class. To use an animal metaphor it would look like this:

```
class Animal
 ...
end

class Mammal < Animal
 ...
end

class Feline < Mammal
 ...
end

class Cat < Feline
 ...
end

class Lion < Cat
 ...
end

...
```

In PHP, there is `__destruct` method that runs when you destroy/delete a class. And should that class extend another class, you simply add `parent::__destruct()` to the class's `__destruct` method like this:

```
public function __destruct() {
  // Clean up code for this class here
  ...

  // Execute clean up code for Parent class
  parent::__destruct();
}
```

I could have a similar method for all the classes except `Animal`. Since it doesn't extend anything, the `parent::__destruct();` line is no longer valid.

However, as I understand it, Ruby doesn't have a method like this for its objects. A finalizer can be set, but I decided to just put in a `cleanup` method I can call whenever I want to destroy/delete a class. That would take care of anything that needed doing prior to my setting the class to `nil`.

This raises a new problem though. If the method is always named `cleanup` and I call `lion_instance.cleanup`, I assume it calls the `Lion#cleanup`. How then to get it to call the `cleanup` in class `Cat` and then `Feline` and on down the chain?

Or is this a wrong approach and you have a better idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ruby idiom for this is to yield to a block which does work, and when the block returns, do cleanup.  Ruby's built-in "File.open" does this:

```
File.open("/tmp/foo") do |file|
  file.puts "foo"
end
```

When the block ends, the file is closed for you, without you having to do anything.  This is an excellent idiom.  Here's how you might implement something like that:

```
class Foo

  def self.open(*args)
     foo = new(*args)
     yield foo
     foo.close
  end

  def initialize
    # do setup here
  end

  def close
    # do teardown here
  end

end
```

And to use it:

```
Foo.open do |foo|
  # use foo
end
```

`Foo#close` will be caused automatically after the `end`

---

This will work with subclassing as well.  That's because class methods are inherited just as are instance methods.  Here's the superclass:

```
class Superclass

  def self.open(*args)
    o = new(*args)
    yield o
    o.close
  end

  def initialize
    # common setup behavior
  end

  def close
    # common cleanup behavior
  end

end
```

and two derived classes:

```
class Foo < Superclass

  def initialize
    super
    # do subclass specific setup here
  end

  def close
    super
    # do subclass specific teardown here
  end

end

class Bar < Superclass

  def initialize
    super
    # do subclass specific setup here
  end

  def close
    super
    # do subclass specific teardown here
  end

end
```

to use:

```
Foo.open do |foo|
  # use foo
end

Bar.open do |bar|
  # use bar
end
```

---

If you *really* need to make sure that cleanup happens no matter what, then use an *ensure* clause in the class method:

```
  def self.open(*args)
     foo = new(*args)
     begin
       yield foo
     ensure
       foo.close
     end
  end
```

This way, cleanup happens even if there is an exception in the block.

Comment: I see how this would work nicely for `class Foo ... end` but not `class Foo < Bar ... end`

Comment: @gabe, Good point.  I've added an example of subclassing with this pattern.

Comment: So there's nothing special that needs to go into the Foo initialize method to say call Superclass.open? What about order of operation? In other words, does the Foo.open complete before Superclass.open? And likewise for close.

Comment: @gabe, Nothing special at all.  There isn't actually a Foo.open, really.  There's just a Superclass.open, but when you call Foo.open, class Foo finds that it doesn't know how to do that, so it asks its superclass.  The superclass does know how to do it, so it does.

Comment: Ignorant (edging on really dumb) question: May I assume Open3 works this way as well? If I use it to run a system command and use a block to consume the pipes it returns, can I assume I've done my part to clean up after myself?

Comment: @Christopher, Yes.  You can see this yourself: In your ruby installation, find open3.rb, and look for popen_run.  You'll see an ensure block that closes file handles.

Comment: @WayneConrad Thanks! I figured it was the case, but wanted someone to validate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ObjectSpace.define_finalizer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html#M001527)

Something like:

```
class Animal
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, proc { # your code })
   end
end
```

Comment: I've read that the define_finalizer is prett bug prone to the way it has be implemented. However, those comments were from 2010 so maybe they no longer apply.

Answer (score 1):

Well since no one answered your question about the method moving its way up the inheritance chain...

```
class Cat
  def rawr
    puts "rawr"
  end
end

class Kitty < Cat
  def rawr
    puts "meow"
    super
  end
end

Cat.new.rawr
"Rawr"

Kitty.new.rawr
"rawr"
"meow"
```

Within a method, you can access the superclass's method of the same name by calling super.

Comment: That's the missing piece for me. Wayne had stated above that the Superclass.open would get executed when it didn't find .open in Foo. However, I wanted a .open in each class to do specific things.  Thanks again.