# What does it mean to destroy a class

Tags: ruby, class

Someone used the phrase "destroy a class" and I was skeptical that it meant anything at all, and decided to do a search and it looks like destroying classes seems to be an actual concept, as shown in [How to properly destroy a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536845/how-to-properly-destroy-a-class)

What does it mean to destroy a class?
How would I destroy a class in Ruby? (if that makes sense at all)

Comment: You shouldn't be promoting class warfare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather destroying, you may [remove the constant](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-remove_const). Remember `class`(s) are nothing but constants.

```
class C;end
C.name # => "C"

self.class.send(:remove_const,:C) 
C.name # uninitialized constant C (NameError)
```

When you are doing `class C;end`, it means you are creating the instance of `Class`(constant assignment) and assigning that instance to constant `C`. `#remove_const` method actually doing the un-assignment, and returns the `Class` instance, which you can assign to another constant.

```
class C
  def self.foo
    12
  end
end

C.foo # => 12
M = self.class.send(:remove_const,:C) 
M.foo # => 12
C.foo # uninitialized constant C (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important rule to learn is, that in Ruby, destroying classes is no different from destroying any other objects. Usually, you have a few fixed classes assigned to constants, that are never destroyed. It is a good, but fairly underused practice to create parametrized subclasses, also of class `Class`, which may get destroyed during the program execution, just like any other object. The destruction itself is performed by the garbage collector, which is normally of no concern to the programmer.

Note: The article you link to does not talk about destroying classes, but about instantiating and destroying the instances.

Comment: But aren't classes instances of class Class themselves?

Comment: Yes, they are. Even class `Class` itself is an instance of class `Class`, that is, itself.